# Damned if you do, damned if you don't: Rust compiler complains regardless whether there's a lifetime parameter or not

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to decide whether I should add a lifetime parameter to my impls, but it seems I'm in a "damned if you do, damned if you don't" situation because the compiler complains regardless whether there's a lifetime parameter or not.

```rust
pub struct TurtleRef<'a> {
    t: &'a BorrowedTurtle<'a>,
}

impl TurtleRef<'_> {
    pub fn borrowed_turtle(&self) -> BorrowedTurtle {
        *self.t
    }

    pub fn new(r: Turtle) -> TurtleRef {
        TurtleRef{t: &BorrowedTurtle{ t:r}}
    }
}

pub struct BorrowedTurtle<'a> {
    t: Turtle<'a>,
}

impl<'a> std::ops::Deref for BorrowedTurtle<'_> {
    type Target = Turtle<'a>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.t
    }
}

impl<'a> std::ops::DerefMut for BorrowedTurtle<'_> {
    type Target = Turtle<'a>;
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &self.t
    }
}

pub struct Turtle<'a> {
    children: Vec<Turtle<'a>>,
}
```

Turtle has more fields, but I removed them for simplicity. You can see the code snippet [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c790bff581b7cc9d8a21f6145f2cd5c1). The code throws the error

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/campus.rs:54:6
   |
54 | impl<'a> std::ops::Deref for BorrowedTurtle<'_> {
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

No problem, I'll just remove the parameter since it's causing such a fuss. But after removing it, I get a whole bunch of new errors:

```
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
  --> src/campus.rs:55:26
   |
55 |     type Target = Turtle<'a>;
   |                          ^^ undeclared lifetime
   |
help: consider introducing lifetime `'a` here
   |
54 | impl<'a> std::ops::Deref for BorrowedTurtle<'_> {
   |     ^^^^
help: consider introducing lifetime `'a` here
   |
55 |     type Target<'a> = Turtle<'a>;
   |                ^^^^
```

Whatever you say, I'll just go ahead and add that parameter to target. But now I get yet another error:

```
error[E0658]: generic associated types are unstable
  --> src/campus.rs:55:5
   |
55 |     type Target<'a> = Turtle<'a>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #44265 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265> for more information
```

So no matter what I do, it seems I run into a major error. How do I stop these errors without starting over from scratch? I'd like to keep the impls, structs, and deref functions, so the only thing I should change is their implementation.

On another note, I get the error

```
error[E0437]: type `Target` is not a member of trait `std::ops::DerefMut`
  --> src/campus.rs:64:5
   |
64 |     type Target = Turtle<'a>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `std::ops::DerefMut`
```

because Turtle doesn't implement DerefMut, and in fact Turtle should not implement DerefMut. Is there a slight modification of Turtle which results in something that already implements DerefMut?

Comment: @Stargateur The 2 structs and 3 impls that I posted rely on each other. There's a lot of functions regarding Turtle that I left out in order to minimize the code. DerefMut and Deref rely on BorrowedTurtle, which TurtleRef and impl TurtleRef rely on.

Comment: @Stargateur But I see what you mean about reproducibility, so I added a portion of the Turtle struct. You should be able to see all 3 errors that I'm concerned about now: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c790bff581b7cc9d8a21f6145f2cd5c1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. Firstly:

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/campus.rs:54:6
   |
54 | impl<'a> std::ops::Deref for BorrowedTurtle<'_> {
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

You either use an anonymous lifetime or you don't. Here, you declare the `'a`, so *use* it:

```rust
impl<'a> std::ops::Deref for BorrowedTurtle<'a> {
```

To use an elided lifetime, you don't have to declare it:

```rust
impl std::ops::Deref for BorrowedTurtle<'_> {
```

However, here you have to refer to the lifetime in `Target`, so you cannot elide it.

Second:

```
error[E0437]: type `Target` is not a member of trait `std::ops::DerefMut`
  --> src/lib.rs:28:5
   |
28 |     type Target = Turtle<'a>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `std::ops::DerefMut`
```

`DerefMut` does not have a `Target` member because it reuses that from its supertrait, `Deref`. This is to ensure that items must `Deref` and `DerefMut` to the same `Target`:

```rust
impl<'a> std::ops::Deref for BorrowedTurtle<'a> {
    type Target = Turtle<'a>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.t
    }
}

impl std::ops::DerefMut for BorrowedTurtle<'_> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.t
    }
}
```

Lastly, you will now get errors that `'a` is not used:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `'a` is never used
  --> src/lib.rs:15:27
   |
15 | pub struct BorrowedTurtle<'a> {
   |                           ^^ unused parameter
   |
   = help: consider removing `'a`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
```

This is because you have a couple of recursive types where the lifetime isn't actually being used:

```rust
// 'a isn't actually used for anything

pub struct Turtle<'a> {
    children: Vec<Turtle<'a>>,
}

pub struct BorrowedTurtle<'a> {
    t: Turtle<'a>,
}
```

I will assume that for the purpose of this answer you omitted other relevant fields that use the `'a`, so that's all!

Comment: Who knew that writing code without lifetimes, then repeatedly recompiling and following lifetime suggestions listed after the errors would cause such trouble. Can't believe I missed that DerefMut is a special type of Deref (it's just like Java subclasses), but the anonymous lifetimes were due to me being careless and adding them as the compiler recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Since `DerefMut` inherit from `Deref`, you don't have to specify `Target`, `pub trait DerefMut: Deref {` use the `Target` define in `Deref` implementation.

Deref trait is very special, it can't really be use by "normal" user, almost only std can implement it for new type.

This is because it's borrow self and return a reference of "something else" problem is this something else can't be temporary, std use it control over rust ecosystem to be able to do that for example `Vec` implementation:

```rust
impl<T, A: Allocator> ops::DerefMut for Vec<T, A> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [T] {
        unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts_mut(self.as_mut_ptr(), self.len) }
    }
}
```

as you can see slice is a "fat pointer" so it doesn't need more than a reference to be valid, you can almost only implement `Deref` to return `Target` for type like `slice`.

Another example is for `PathBuf`:

```rust
impl ops::Deref for PathBuf {
    type Target = Path;
    #[inline]
    fn deref(&self) -> &Path {
        Path::new(&self.inner)
    }
}
```

Here it's even more clear `Path::new` create a fat pointer. So, Target can't be something else that something that can't be self contained or already exist in your `Self`.

As the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) said:

> Because of this, Deref should only be implemented for smart pointers to avoid confusion.

I think what you really want is to implement [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html). All that said... here a working code:

```rust
impl<'a> std::ops::Deref for BorrowedTurtle<'a> {
    type Target = Turtle<'a>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.t
    }
}

impl std::ops::DerefMut for BorrowedTurtle<'_> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.t
    }
}
```

Do as you wish.